# Handling the response from `res.download()` on the client side (Rest api, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So the express docs have a download function in the following form:

```
res.download(cvUrl, cvName, function (err) {
  if (err) {
     // ...
  } else {
     // ...
  }
})
```

I think this would normally trigger the browser to download the file automatically, with the correct filename, as the response headers are correctly set and I'm receiving a file. But I'm handling the download like this:

```
this.admin.getCv(cvUrl).then(cv => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([cv]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'test'); // how can I access the filename here?
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
})
```

Is it possible to access the filename (cvName) on the frontend? Adding it as a second parameter seemed like the obvious solution, but didn't work. Any hints would be great,

Thanks,

Nick

**Edit:

```
import JRS from '../api/jrs';

export default class Admin {
    getCv (applicantId) {
        return JRS.get(`/admin/cvs/${applicantId}`);
    }
}
```

// JRS.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true
});
```

Comment: res.download will do no good for you if you are downloading it with ajax, better to make a link instead. if you need to send data, put it as url search parameters

Comment: Hi @Endless, not entirely sure what you mean RE making a link? I've managed to get the filename + ext and what I think is the file itself to the frontend - although to be fair I'm suffering with unreadable content now when I try and open it...

Comment: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/wiki/Saving-a-remote-file

Comment: The end of that link was just what I needed. I had to set the `responseType: 'blob'` on the axios get request, in addition to creating a new blob. I think the browser was trying to process the data and making it unreadable. Thanks!

Comment: Still think you should go with a server side solution instead of using axios or any ajax method

Comment: I still don't understand if I'm totally honest. I still need to get the file to the front end from the server don't I? I've added the code that works for me in an answer below in case I've not been that clear what I'm trying to do. Just happy it's working tbh! (but would like to understand what you're suggesting) :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ydrsnvfz/1/

Comment: Nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `download` method adds a `Content-Disposition` header to the response, so you just need to read that.

It looks like your `getCv` function makes an HTTP request, extracts the body from the response, then resolves a promise with that body.

You'll need to modify the `getCv` function so it :

- Reads the `Content-Disposition` header (how you do that depends on which HTTP API you are using)
- Extracts the filename from it (something like `contentDisposition.match(/filename=(.*)/)`)
- Includes that in the data you are resolving the promise with (which will probably mean passing an object containing the filename and body instead of just the body)

Then you'll need to change your `then` callback so it handles that object instead of expecting the body directly.

---

That said, it would probably be easier to just link to the URL directly instead of fetching the data with JSON, converting it to a `data:` URL, generating a link and triggering a client on it.

Comment: Hi Quentin, yeah `getCV()` uses an axios instance to make a `get` request to the route needed. I'm now just trying to work out how to read the Content-Disposition header like you suggest. It's visible in the response - does that mean I don't need to set the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` on the server? I've added my axios instance / `getCv()` function to the OP. Thanks for the help

Comment: @NickW — You might need to set that too, but there was no suggestion there was anything cross-origin in the question.

Comment: My mistake - pretty new at this. Am I wrong in thinking that I should be able to access the headers on `cv.data.headers`? I mean I must be wrong because it's undefined, but that seems to be what's suggested in other answers. I've now set `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`.

Comment: See https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema - the headers are not inside the data.

Comment: XD They're not, you're right! Got the filename and ext working great thanks. Just to double check, you'd expect cv.data to be the file itself, right? I'm just getting unreadable content when I attempt to open it, and logging it shows a sequence of mostly ���

Comment: I would, but you don't seem to be touching `cv.data` at all

Comment: Have updated my current code in an answer below (didn't want to change the context of the original question). If you think it looks ok at least that narrows the problem down a bit!

Answer (score 0):

This works for accessing the filename and ext, and fixes the problem I was having with axios/streams/unreadable content, in case it helps anyone else.

For the unreadable content, it was important to add the responseType to the request.

// Client side

```
axios.get('http://localhost:4000/download', {responseType: 'blob'}).then(res => {
    downloadFile(res);
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

const downloadFile = (res) => {
    const contentDisposition = res.headers['content-disposition'];
    const fileName = contentDisposition.split(';')[1].split('=')[1];

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', `${fileName}`);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
}
```

// Server

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:2000');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Content-Disposition');
    next();
});

app.get('/download', (req, res, next) => {
    const test = 'sample.doc';
    const fileUrl = path.join(__dirname, test);
    const fileName = path.basename(fileUrl);
    res.header('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileName}`);
    const myReadableStream = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, test));
    res.status(200);
    myReadableStream.pipe(res);
});
```